# Why won't my divs center within their parent?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've got two divs within a parent div that I'm trying to switch over to 100% width after a specific media query so that they take up the whole screen. For some reason they just will not center and take up the whole width. What is causing this?

```css
/*Non Media Query CSS */
.mainContent {
 width: 100%; 
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 
}

.meContainer {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}

.me {
 width: 35%; 
}

.articleContainer {
 width: 50%; 
 float: right;
    text-align: left;
 padding-top:5%;
 margin:auto;
}

article {
 width:86%; 
 line-height: 115%;
    text-align:justify;
}

.container {
 width: 100%; 
 clear: both;
 text-align: center; 
}

/* The CSS I'm struggling With */



@media only screen and (max-width: 424px) {
.mainContent {
 width: 100%; 
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 
}

.meContainer {
 width: 100%;
 clear:both;
 text-align: center;
 
}

.articleContainer {
 width: 100%; 
 clear:both;
    text-align: center;
 padding-top:5%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
 <div class="meContainer">
     <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5834/22284877876_c2a7d1f6e0_c.jpg" alt="Portrait of Brian Funderburke" class="me">
    </div>
    
    <div class="articleContainer">
        <article>
        Hi, I'm Brian Funderburke! I'm a freelance photographer and designer based in Fredericksburg, Virginia. My work has been featured in Photographer's Forum Annual Photography Contest as well as the Popular page on 500px. I've been shooting photography and designing since 2013, and have a Bachelor's in Graphic Design with a minor in photography. When not shooting photography or designing, I enjoy spending time hiking along the Blue Ridge Mountains, reading, and other hobbies.
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/92rkwya2/) what you need?

Comment: first of all, is your media query actually firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the `article` is 86%. Since you can't align a block element with `text-align`, it's still flush to the left.

Solution: give the article `margin:0 auto`.

```css
/*Non Media Query CSS */

.mainContent {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.meContainer {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.me {
  width: 35%;
}
.articleContainer {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5%;
  margin: auto;
}
article {
  width: 86%;
  line-height: 115%;
  text-align: justify;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The CSS I'm struggling With */

@media only screen and (max-width: 424px) {
  .mainContent {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }
  .meContainer {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .articleContainer {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5%;
  }
  article {
    margin: 0 auto
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
  <div class="meContainer">
    <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5834/22284877876_c2a7d1f6e0_c.jpg" alt="Portrait of Brian Funderburke" class="me">
  </div>

  <div class="articleContainer">
    <article>
      Hi, I'm Brian Funderburke! I'm a freelance photographer and designer based in Fredericksburg, Virginia. My work has been featured in Photographer's Forum Annual Photography Contest as well as the Popular page on 500px. I've been shooting photography and
      designing since 2013, and have a Bachelor's in Graphic Design with a minor in photography. When not shooting photography or designing, I enjoy spending time hiking along the Blue Ridge Mountains, reading, and other hobbies.
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code snippet seems to work when I test it in chrome, but when I actually implement it I still have the same issue.

Comment: If your real code is more complicated, you should try to post something in your question text that looks more like the real code!

Comment: it's not more complicated. I think I had messed something up because I just deleted everything I had written and your solution worked when I re inserted it.

Answer (score 1):

you have given float property in child div's also so you have to give following css to child div

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 424px) {
.meContainer, .articleContainer{
    width: 100%;
    float:none; 
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;

}
```

Comment: so when trying to override a float I had previously placed on an element all I need to do is change it to float:none? For some reason I thought clear:both; would accomplish the same thing

Comment: no clear:both will work for clearing the float nature of the document for next div but for responsive you have to mention float:none to destroy float nature...and dont forget to mark it as relevant answer if it is :)

Answer (score 1):

You may not even need the 'only screen' part.  I only increased the size b/c my browser couldn't shrink to '424px'.

`@media (max-width: 600px)`

If the media query is actually firing, then the problem lies in your CSS in the media query.  For me, your image centers and is on it's own line, and so is the 'article' text, you just need to center that inner `<article>` tag.

```
.articleContainer article {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```